# Troubles with facebook fql reading page fans

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a problem with facebook jql and javascript sdk in an facebook app tab. If a user is logged in, then i want to read if the user is fan of the page. If so, redirect to a specific fan page, else redirect to another page. But for some reasons, the fql resultset is empty (but i am the administrator of the page, and of course fan of it ;-) )

here is a code snippet:

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {
// The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
// login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
// have logged in to the app.
FB.api({
method:     'fql.query', 
query:  'SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=188705819498'
}, function(resp) {
if (resp.length) {          

self.location.href = 'fanpage.html';
} else {
self.location.href = 'infopage.html';
}
}
);
```

Comment: Do you have `user_likes` permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need user_likes permission to read his/her likes. Try that if it doesn't help try PHP SDK. I had such problems when the javascript and PHP were returning different results.